# Please reopen What does “mode” mean in “modal verb”?

Tags: support, closed-questions

Why was https://english.stackexchange.com/q/186168/50720 closed as off-topic by members of the community? Maybe different members have a different view on this.

My trouble is summarised by Professor Lawler's instructive comment below it. 'Commonly-available references' don't answer it. Please reopen?

Comment: While the question might be worth reopening, it's still problematic. I don't think it makes sense to ask which sense of *mode* applies in *modal verb*. Further more asking about auxiliaries is asking too many things for one question.

Comment: You state a number of questions there, but all of them seem to be elementary. "What does 'mode' mean in 'modal'?" - look up the definition of 'modal' and see if 'mode' is mentioned. "How do you relate modal to auxiliary?" Again, look them both up; a modal is a kind of auxiliary.

Comment: @curiousdannii Please explain 'I don't think it makes sense to ask which sense of mode applies in modal verb.' ?

Comment: @Mitch I did; 'mode' does appear there.

Comment: One definition out of many is pretty self-explanatory - "Grammar : noting or pertaining to mood." The interesting question here, if any, is why the derivation isn't 'moodal'. Are you asking that?

Comment: Because it comes from Latin _modus_ 'measure'. The double O is just an English spelling variant. That's why _mood_ has a meaning associated with emotion as well as grammar; it's been around a long time; all of them are just O-grade versions of the PIE root [*med-](http://web.archive.org/web/20080629144346/http://www.bartleby.com/61/roots/IE305.html).

Answer (score 2):

Just so you know, I voted to reopen the question. It seems similar to my own [*What exactly is an “adverb”?*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/what-exactly-is-an-adverb), which came perilously close to being closed as General Reference before gaining traction and becoming my second most upvoted question.

Apropos which, I'm still a bit piqued that my [*Where does “Don't bogart that joint” come from?*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87596/where-does-dont-bogart-that-joint-come-from) remains closed as GR. Okay - it's obvious once it's pointed out. But I couldn't easily satisfy my curiosity anywhere else online at the time, and I generally consider my google-fu to be pretty good.

As John Lawler says (and he should know! :),...

> Modality is a [very complex subject](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/Modality.pdf). It's the source of the grammatical term mood (as in "subjunctive mood"), and it also uses [a special variety of logic called Modal Logic](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf). ***It's precisely on target here***.

---

Some folk here seem to think I habitually closevote questions as Too Basic, but I reject that. Mostly I think [there are no dumb questions, only dumb answers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_such_thing_as_a_stupid_question). I often closevote ELU questions because I think they're not suitable for this site, and should have been asked on [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).

I've no doubt entire *books* could be written about linguistic *moods, modality, modal verbs*, etc. I don't want to see an incredibly long answer on ELU trying to cover every aspect of the concept, but it would be nice if someone could post a relatively short (but authoritative) answer. Which can't happen while the question remains closed.

Comment: *Modality* may be a complex subject, but the question doesn't ask about modality. The question asks what *modal* means, not what *modal* is. There is a gigantic difference there.

Comment: @KitFox: I utterly reject that position. You're just splitting hairs about whether the OP was asking about the (contextless?) meaning of the word *modal*, as opposed to asking what exactly we're talking about when we use any of these terms on ELU. I don't have the faintest idea how to distinguish a *modal verb* from an *auxiliary verb*. Without doing some (probably taxing) research, I don't even know whether or to what extent those two terms overlap - and I'm a competent speaker with my tertiary education primarily focussed on language. So I fully expect and wish the question to be reopened.

Comment: (I also have no idea whether grammatical ***mood*** and ***mode*** are the same or different things. These are potentially interesting points which might reasonably be addressed by a decent answer once the question *is* reopened.)

Comment: I have every reason to believe my interpretation of the situation is correct. I invite you to edit the question to reflect your expectation of how it could generate good answers. It would very likely contribute to it being re-opened.

Comment: @KitFox: I think the problem here is simply that the OP has raised a few hackles by asking so many questions that people think are fairly pointless (and the ill-advised use of ***brook*** in this particular question probably didn't help). I remain of the opinion that the question *as originally framed* should not have been closed, and it shouldn't be necessary for someone like me to supplement that question with an outline of what a good answer might look like in order to get it reopened. All it needs is for people to think more objectively about the situation and *change their minds*.

Comment: That's as may be; but shouldn't everyone who wants the question re-opened be trying to change people's minds?

Comment: @Andrew: I really do think this one is akin to the initial reaction to my "adverb" question - there's a predisposition to close it, and that has unfortunately carried the day. It seems defeatist to say the question *might be okay if re-worded*, or that it would only become okay if someone sketched out the gist of a possibly stellar answer. Sure - I want people to change their minds (or others to overrule the original closevote). But I think that's because the decision was *wrong in the first place*, not because it's not *presented* well (lots of much worse questions remain sanctioned).